# How do I stop Ubuntu 12.10 heating up so much?

Tags: overheating

I am dual booting Windows 8 with Ubuntu 12.10. When I use Windows 8, it hardly ever heats up, while in ubuntu it heats up very quickly. I am using a netbook and I do not want to give up at Ubuntu, but also I do not want to upgrade any hardware. the netbook is a acer aspire one d257, it has a intel atom n570, igb ram and 6 cell lion battery. i do not know what graphics card it has.

Comment: what is your graphics card? please execute `lspci | grep VGA` in terminal and post output. Also include laptop information.

Comment: please write your full laptop Specifications like it's name , processor and VGA and please try to check if you vga driver working do or not because it can do this problem so please check this in Details window write in terminal 'gnome-control-center' and go to Details and in Graphics see if it's write or write unkown put please provide us alot of information about your system and write this in terminal 'sudo lshw -c Display'

Comment: @guntbert thanks, after several years, I have finally decided to merge them together

Answer (score 1):

If you are having problems with battery, CPU or overall overheating of the machine I suggest you try [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html). Originally designed to increase the battery performance, it also offers a lot more than just that !

Also, if you type "sudo tlp-stat" (after installing) you will get all the information you need out about your machine, and I bet that is going to help a lot of people here to help you even better.

Still, it is imperative that you find out your graphic card type. If it is an NVidia, there are ways to control the fans through its driver's software (Not sure if that is also possible if you have an ATI or INTEL).

Answer (score 0):

i am using a different profile. the laptop is a acer aspire one d257, a intel atom n570  imb L2cache it is a 1.66ghx processor. igb ram. 6 cell lion battery.

The graphics card is just an integrated one as it is just a netbook.